# Friendly_id: In a model how to slug a second column value when value in first column is absent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I am using Ruby 2.1.1 and Rails 4.0.4.

In my model I have two columns A & B.

How do I slug value of B when value in column A is absent?

I want to keep column A value primarily. It is only when the value in column A is absent.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try using an instance method (as per [this documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/FriendlyId/Slugged)):

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  friendly_id :default_value
  def default_value
    column_a || column_b
  end
end
```

Comment: But how this method choose column b when column a field is absent? Should it be something like, if column_a.present? :first_name else :id-last_name end

Comment: If the value of column A is absent then I must use the value of column B for the slug.

Comment: Okay let me refactor my answer for you

Comment: There you got buddy - I think that's what you need

Comment: Can you explain me a bit why there is a Time.now.to_i is there?

Comment: It is not working. When trying to save old record by Model.find_each(&:save) it is just loading few ones from column A but not any from column B.